# Increase the distance between x axis factor and the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to customize the distance between the x axis factor and the plot in ggplot?

```
library(ggplot2)
female <- ggplot(gender_and_age[(1:7),], aes(x = gender_and_age, y = count)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'lightpink1')+ theme_light() + geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f%%", count/sum(count) * 100)),  vjust = -.5)
```

return this plot [image: female]

I want to set a space between "13-17","18-24","25-34", "35-44", "45-45","55-64","65+" and the plot

This is what I want

[image]

Comment: @ycw I think that the OP is not asking about moving the label `gender_and_age` but rather separating the x-axis ticks from the histogram.  He needs to adjust lower ylim.

Comment: @G5W I could be wrong. But based on the last sentence of the post, it looks like the OP wants more space between "all the x-axis labels" and "the plot", which is the link I am referencing is about. Please provide a solution for the OP related to the adjustment of ylim, or we can wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: that's what I want exactly @G5W
https://scontent-cai1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p173x172/21751356_1126278870837197_1879416366894612147_n.jpg?oh=4a32a76ef01611b40d5a304b345287bb&oe=5A4164CB

Comment: You could get some space between the bars and the labels by adjusting `ylim`  but that is not exactly what you are asking for.  It would make the grid bigger.

Comment: @norhanabdelaziz ; using the link posted by ycw, you can do `p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=20, r=0, l=0, b=0)))`  : change `t` to suit